# Get the key of an object that a function uses

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a `props` object, which contains multiple keys `keyA`, `keyB`...

And I have 3 functions `funcA`, `funcB` and `funcC`, each having one argument which is `props`. However, each function will use zero, one or more key/values of their `props` argument, and I wish to know which keys have been used by each function.

For example:

```
const funcA = props => {/* do something with props.keyA and props.keyB */}

const funcB = props => {/* do something with props.keyC */}

const funcC = props => {/* do nothing with props */}
```

And I wish to have a mechanism (i.e. a wrapper function, or a wrapper class...), which, when `func{A,B,C}` is called, will console.log the keys with which the function has been called:

```
// I wish to have the following lines console.logged:
funcA is using keyA and keyB
funcB is using keyC
funcC is not using anything
```

My first step is to create a `Proxy` on the `props` object, in the following way:

```
const propsProxy = new Proxy(props, {
  get (target, key) {
    console.log(`${key} has been used.`);
    return target[key];
  }
}

// ...

funcA(propsProxy); // Logs "keyA has been used. keyB has been used."
funcB(propsProxy); // Logs "keyC has been used."
funcC(propsProxy);
```

But then I'm stuck on how to log the function name too.

Edit: After reading some comments, it seems I need to add some clarifications. Let's make it more practical.

I'm actually writing this lib, let's call it `wrapper`, which end developers would use it like:

```
import wrapper from 'wrapper';

// User defines funcA=..., funcB=..., funcC=... and props

wrapper(funcA, funcB, funcC, props); // Will call funcA(props), funcB(props) and funcC(props)
// Should log:
// funcA is using keyA and keyB
// funcB is using keyC
// funcC is not using anything
```

Question: please write the code for `wrapper`?

Comment: you could move the function into another object and use a proxy for logging.

Comment: `console.log("funcA"); funcA(propsProxy);`. ...

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Needs to be dynamic, I may have `funcD`, `funcE` dynamically added, I'm expecting to use `Function.name` somewhere.

Comment: @NinaScholz can you explain your idea?

Comment: @amaurymartiny Well you can only do that when you pass the function to the proxy, not the other way round. Something like `getLog(funcA)` could actually use `.name` inside `getLog`, because it knew about `funcA`. In the current code, your proxy does not know about the functions (except perhaps from a stack trace, but that's a bad idea).

Comment: To get the name of the caller function you can use [**arguments.callee**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee), example: `function aaa () { console.log(arguments.callee.name); }`

Comment: @codtex No, that's not applicable here. (And deprecated anyway).

Comment: Can you implement `wrapper` so that it does the calls itself? Something like: `wrapper(props, funcA, funcB, funcC, ...);`. That will be easy to do.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yes, just edited.

Comment: @amaurymartiny `function wrapper(...fns, props) { const propsProxy = …; for (const fn of fns) { console.log(fn.name); fn(propsProxy); }}` should do that? What's the problem you have?

Comment: @Bergi I need `fn.name` and `is using keys...` in a single console.log.

Comment: @amaurymartiny Then make your proxy so that it doesn't log on every single access, but rather collects the property names in an array, and you can log it together with the function name in the end.

Comment: @Bergi exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `wrapper` like so:

```
function wrapper(props, ...funcs) {
  funcs.forEach(function(func) {                                       // for each function func passed as argument
    var used = [];                                                     // this will be the array of used property names (duplicates included)

    var propsProxy = new Proxy(props, {                                // set up a new proxy of props
      get(target, key) {
        used.push(key);                                                // ... which add the key used to used array
        return target[key];
      }
    });

    func(propsProxy);                                                  // call func with the proxy object

    console.log(func.name + " used " + (used.length? used.join(" and "): "nothing")); // log the results
  });
}
```

**Example:**

```js
function funcA(props) {
  var result = props.propA + props.propC;
}

function funcB(props) {
  if(props.propA) {
    return true;
  }
}

function funcC(props) {
}

function wrapper(props, ...funcs) {
  funcs.forEach(function(func) {
    var used = [];

    var propsProxy = new Proxy(props, {
      get(target, key) {
        used.push(key);
        return target[key];
      }
    });

    func(propsProxy);
    
    console.log(func.name + " used " + (used.length? used.join(" and "): "nothing"));
  });
}

wrapper({
  propA: 5,
  propB: 6,
  propC: 7
}, funcA, funcB, funcC);
```

Comment: Yes, works. Though it defines `funcs.length` new Proxies. I'd do a simple refactor to put `new Proxy` outside of the forEach, and probably add an internal "currentFunctionCalled" variable.

Comment: @amaurymartiny Yeah, it still needs a little polishing but the idea is there.

Comment: @amaurymartiny Or use one proxy and one `used` array outside `forEach` and for each function you just clear `used` array.